# iOS14 UIDatePicker change color on certain dates

Tags: swift, uikit, ios14

I have an application that should have an inline datepicker showing unavailable dates in gray color.

This is how the datePicker looks like currently:

[image]

And this is my objective:

[image]

You can see that for example, 26 and 27 are in grey colour.

I now that tintColor changes the current day and the selected day colour in ios14 and setValue(UIColor, forKeyPath: "textColor") changes all dates in a wheel style datepicker.

My question is, should be possible to change a certain date color? or the only way would be using a custom UIPickerView?

Thanks

Comment: No, it is not possible to change apples date pickers. Get a library